# Convert &#____ to \u____ in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, html, unicode

I want to show a special character.

I found this [link which displays everything](http://amp-what.com/?tagline=Search%3Cbr%3EUnicode%20Characters&utm_expid=63334077-0&utm_referrer=http://t.co/oklb2ro0#q=arrow).

let's take for example this char :

[image]

2 questions )

- how can I convert `&darr;` ,  `&#8595;` to `\u____`unicode char ? ( c#)
- When should I use `&darr;` vs `&#8595;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&darr;")
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#8595;")
```

The above is .NET 4.0 and above, for prior versions, use `System.Web.HttpUtility`.

Both will produce a string containing `↓`.

You can take this string, get the first (and only) character from it - this will be a C#, UTF16 character.

I would suggest using `&darr;` instead of the numeric character reference if you must use character references, as it is more readable. If you can use the `↓` directly, that is best.

Comment: keeping the actual  `↓` will force me to save the ASPX file as utf (or unicode - I don't remember )file... which can cause me sometime to forget doing it....

Comment: @RoyiNamir - I thought Visual Studio uses UTF-8 by default.

Comment: Strange , I just tested : pasted the char and saved. and no warnning.(dialog box). maybe it was on 2008. ( im on 2010)......any way you right

Answer (score 1):

In c# always use unicode escape convention.  For you code point it would be `\u8559`.

```
Console.WriteLine("Down arrow - \u8559");
```

The character entity reference `&darr;` can be used in HTML and XML.  However, most processors don't know this name. So use `&#8595`.

```
<text>Down arrow - &#8585;</text>
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity_reference and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: So just replace `&#` with `\u` ?

Comment: You got it. `&#` is HTML/XML convention.  `\u` is C# convention.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - and remove the trailing `;`. Though this is error prone.

Comment: For me, down arrow is `\u2193`, you can check this for example by `Encoding.Unicode.GetString(new byte[] { 0x93, 0x21 });`. The `\u8595` is unrecognized I suppose - as it prints `?`.